# Buttons below RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to put buttons below a `RecyclerView`, in such a way that when you scroll all the way down in the `RecyclerView`, there should be the button (Previous/Next)

The XML I am trying is given below. But the `RecyclerView` takes all the space.

Please note I have tried putting `layout_height=0` and `layout_weight=1`, but it still is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.app.home"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_homepost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/next_prev_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rv_homepost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are just missing `android:orientation="vertical"` in your root `LinearLayout` otherwise it looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this .... there is some changes may be useful for you.

You forgot  `android:orientation="vertical"` property for linear layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.app.home"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_homepost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/next_prev_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rv_homepost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

enjoy coding......